# A while-loop that reads in two ints and then prints them

Tags: c++

I am completely stuck on a drill on chapter 4 of "Programming - Principles and Practice Using C++". The question is:

"Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the loop) reads in two ints and then prints them. Exit the program when a terminating '|' is entered."

This is my code:

```
{
int entryvariable = 0;
int numberofentries = 0;
vector<int>vector1;


while (cin>>entryvariable)
{
    vector1.push_back(entryvariable);
    ++numberofentries;

if (numberofentries % 2 == 0)
    cout<<vector1[numberofentries - 1] << vector1[numberofentries] << "\n";
}
```

This, of course, ends up crashing.

How would I fix this so that it works properly?

(Does anyone have an answer key for this book? It's really well written, but it's impossible to check your answers if you're undertaking self-study.)

Comment: You could read two ints: `while (cin >> v1 >> v2)`. Then there's no need anymore for `vector1` and `numberofentries`.

Answer (score 2):

Indices in C++ are ranging from `0` to `n - 1`. Your code assumes that you can access `vector1[n]` if `vector1.size() == n`. Also, you are only reading one value in each iteration. You can just read two values, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
vector<int>v;
int a=0; 
cin>>a; 
int b=0; 
while (v.size()<2) // insted of 2 it could be another figure for 
                   //   another number of printed figures
{
v.push_back(a); 
cin>>b;
a=b;
}
for (int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
cout<<v[i]<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: Add problem description in the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your `vector1[numberofentries]` is causing the error

A vector starts from `0th`index..

So when your `numberofentries` is 1 ,the value is stored in `vector1[0]` not `vector1[1]`

when your `numberofentries` is 2 ,the value is stored in `vector1[1]` not `vector1[2]`

So your code should be

`cout<<vector1[numberofentries - 2] << vector1[numberofentries-1] << "\n";`

Answer (score 0):

I am working through the same exercises, and have found the google group for the book the best place to ask questions about the exercises and drills, a thread relating to your question can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/ppp-public/%2420chapter%24204%2420drill/ppp-public/aKxBPHfd0p8/DKC5AdNJTLAJ).

Hope this helps.